# How do I use TeX/LaTeX formatting for custom data tips in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex, symbols, string-formatting, datatipfunction

I'm trying to annotate a polar plot with data tips labelled with 'R:...,Theta:...' where theta is actually the Greek symbol, rather than the word spelled out. I'm familiar with string formatting using '\theta' resulting in the symbol, but it doesn't work in this case. Is there a way to apply the LaTeX interpreter to data tips? Here's what I have so far:

```
f1=figure;
t=pi/4;
r=1;
polar(t,r,'.');
dcm_obj = datacursormode(f1);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@polarlabel)
info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
datacursormode on
```

where polarlabel is defined as follows:

```
function txt = polarlabel(empt,event_obj)
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
x=pos(1);
y=pos(2);
[th,r]=cart2pol(x,y);
txt = {['R: ',num2str(r)],...
    ['\Theta: ',num2str(th*180/pi)]};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** This solution is primarily applicable to versions R2014a and older, since it appears to fail for newer versions, specifically R2014b and newer using the [new handle graphics system](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-graphics.html). For newer versions using the new handle graphics system, a solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011448/52738).

---

For some odd reason, the [data cursor tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) in MATLAB forcibly sets the data tip text to be displayed literally instead of with TeX/LaTeX interpreting (even if the [default MATLAB settings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#property_d0e1002285) say to do so). There also appears to be no way of directly setting text properties via the data cursor mode object properties.

However, I've figured out one workaround. If you add the following to the end of your `polarlabel` function, the text should display properly:

```
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on');                       % Show hidden handles
hText = findobj('Type','text','Tag','DataTipMarker');  % Find the data tip text
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','off');                      % Hide handles again
set(hText,'Interpreter','tex');                        % Change the interpreter
```

### Explanation

Every graphics object created in the figure has to have a [handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html). Objects sometimes have their [`'HandleVisibility'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#property_d0e1005510) set to `'off'`, so their handles won't show up in the list of child objects for their parent object, thus making them harder to find. One way around this is to set the [`'ShowHiddenHandles'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/root-properties.html#property_d0e877586) of the [root object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) to `'on'`. This will then allow you to use [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to find the handles of graphics objects with certain properties. (**Note:** You could also use [`findall`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) and not worry about the `'ShowHiddenHandles'` setting)

Turning on [data cursor mode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html) and clicking the plot creates an [hggroup object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hggroup.html), one child of which is the [text object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) for the text that is displayed. The above code finds this text object and changes the [`'Interpreter'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html#property_d0e1002285) to `'tex'` so that the theta symbol is correctly displayed.

Technically, the above code only has to be called once, not every time `polarlabel` is called. However, the text object doesn't exist until the first time you click on the plot to bring up the data tip (i.e. the first time `polarlabel` gets called), so the code has to go in the `UpdateFcn` for the data cursor mode object so that the first data tip displayed has the right text formatting.

Comment: Thanks gnovice, this solution works perfectly! Excellent explanation as well.

Comment: You can replace `findobj` with `findall`, which works regardless of `ShowHiddenHandles` property

Comment: For the record, this seems to have broken in R2015a. Looking into it now.

Comment: The answer is here for newer versions using hg2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011448/how-to-properly-display-tex-strings-in-axes-datatips-matlab-hg2