# How to properly display TeX strings in axes' datatips? (MATLAB hg2)

Tags: matlab, textbox, matlab-figure, undocumented-behavior, matlab-hg2

I have recently tried to run an old piece of code (written on hg1) on a new version of MATLAB (2015a) that has hg2.

I used to be able to do the following (according to the "[gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668559/3372061)-[Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118966/how-to-add-greek-letter-to-data-cursor-in-matlab-figure?lq=1#comment9968456_8119149)" method):

```
function output_txt = customDatatip(~,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

hFig = ancestor(event_obj.Target,'figure'); %// I don't trust gcf ;)

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['\lambda: ',num2str(pos(1)*1000,4) 'nm'],...
              ['T(\lambda): ',num2str(pos(2),4) '%']};

set(findall(hFig, 'Type','text', 'Tag','DataTipMarker'),...
      'Interpreter','tex');     %// Change the interpreter
```

And would get nicely formatted datatip labels with Greek characters.

However, in the new hg2 system, `findall` returns a `0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array`, which renders setting the `Interpreter` useless.

My question is: **How can I set the plot datatip interpreter to (La)TeX in hg2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging using [`uiinspect`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methods--properties---callbacks-of-an-object), I found that the `"TextBox"` is now stored as a `matlab.graphics.shape.internal.GraphicsTip` type of object within `obj`'s `TipHandle` property which, in turn, has an `Interpreter` property! Both properties are `public` and can be set easily using dot notation. I've ended up using the following code:

```
function output_txt = customDatatip(obj,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor // <- Autogenerated comment
% obj          Currently not used (empty) // <- Autogenerated comment, NO LONGER TRUE!
% event_obj    Handle to event object     // <- Autogenerated comment
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings). // <- A.g.c.

hFig = ancestor(event_obj.Target,'figure');

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['\lambda: ',num2str(pos(1)*1000,4) 'nm'],...
              ['T(\lambda): ',num2str(pos(2),4) '%']};

if ishg2(hFig)
    obj.TipHandle.Interpreter = 'tex';
else %// The old version, to maintain backward compatibility:
        set(findall(hFig, 'Type','text', 'Tag','DataTipMarker'),...
            'Interpreter','tex');     % Change the interpreter
end

function tf = ishg2(fig)
try
    tf = ~graphicsversion(fig, 'handlegraphics');
catch
    tf = false;
end
```

Notes:

- The first input to the function (`obj`) is no longer ignored, since it has some use now.
- The `ishg2` function is taken from [this MATLAB Answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/136834#answer_142576).

#### Edit1:

Just noticed that there's another way to check MATLAB's Graphic version (i.e. hg1/hg2) using the following code I found in the wavelet toolbox:

```
function bool = isGraphicsVersion2
%//isGraphicsVersion2 True for Graphic version 2. 

%//   M. Misiti, Y. Misiti, G. Oppenheim, J.M. Poggi 21-Jun-2013.
%//   Last Revision: 04-Jul-2013.
%//   Copyright 1995-2013 The MathWorks, Inc.
%//   $Revision: 1.1.6.1 $  $Date: 2013/08/23 23:45:07 $

try
    bool = ~matlab.graphics.internal.isGraphicsVersion1;
catch
    bool = ~isprop(0,'HideUndocumented');
end
```