# How to programatically update histogram contents and datatip location? (MATLAB hg2)

Tags: matlab, animation, histogram, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

I am trying to make an animation where several datasets are being cycled through in a [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) plot, and a datatip follows the highest bar in every frame, as demonstrated below:

[image: The desired result]

Here's a code which achieves the desired result using a [bar graph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html):

```
%% // Initialization
close all force; clear variables; clc;
%% // Generate some data:
indMax = 20; data = randi(indMax,[5,45]);
%% // Generate the 1st values to plot:
edges = 0.5:1:indMax+0.5;
counts = histcounts(data(1,:),edges);
[~,maxInd] = max(counts);
%% // Create the plot and the datatip:
figure(100); hBar = bar(1:indMax,counts); 
hDT = makedatatip(hBar,maxInd); hDT = handle(hDT);
grid on; hold on; grid minor; xlim([0,indMax+1]); ylim([0,10]);
%% // Update the figure and the datatip:
for indFrame = 2:size(data,1)       
   counts = histcounts(data(indFrame,:),edges);
   [~,maxInd] = max(counts);
   hBar.YData = counts; %// Update bar heights
   hDT.Cursor.DataIndex = maxInd; %// Update datatip location
   %// Alternatively to the above line: hDT.Position = [newX newY newZ];
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
   drawnow;
end
```

Note that the datatip is created using a modified version of the [`makedatatip` submission from FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19877-makedatatip), as per the comment on the submission page (this is true for the 27/06/2012 version of `makedatatip`):

> *a couple of changes need to be made to the code:
>
>   ***********CHANGE 1********* 
>
>   line 122 needs to be: pos = [X(index(n)) Y(index(n)) 0];
>
>   ***********CHANGE 2********* 
>
>   lines 135-141 should be commented OUT*

And also **Change 3:** *line 84 to `Z = [];`*

Since `makedatatip` attempts to acces the `'XData'` and `'YData'` properties of the input handle, which are absent in [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) plots, it refuses to work. So my question is:

**How can datatips be created and updated programmatically in [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) plots (using [matlab-hg2](/questions/tagged/matlab-hg2)), along with the histogram itself?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the solution is quite straight-forward, at least when only a single datatip is needed. Here are the required steps:

1. Replace the bar plot with a histogram:

   ```
   hHist = histogram(data(1,:),edges);
   ```
2. Create the datatip "manually" instead of using `makedatatip`:

   ```
   hDataCursorMgr = datacursormode(ancestor(hHist,'figure'));
   hDT = createDatatip(hDataCursorMgr,hHist);
   ```
3. Update the position as needed:

   ```
   hDT.Cursor.DataIndex = maxInd;
   ```
4. To update the histogram's bar heights, it is not possible to update the `'Values'` property directly (since it's read-only), so one must update the `'Data'` property (and let MATLAB recompute the bar heights on its own):

   ```
   hHist.Data = data(indFrame,:);
   ```

And everything put together:

```
%% // Initialization
close all force; clear variables; clc;
%% // Generate some data:
indMax = 20; data = randi(indMax,[5,45]);
%% // Generate the 1st values to plot:
edges = 0.5:1:indMax+0.5;
counts = histcounts(data(1,:),edges);
[~,maxInd] = max(counts);
%% // Create the plot and the datatip:
figure(100); hHist = histogram(data(1,:),edges);
hDataCursorMgr = datacursormode(ancestor(hHist,'figure'));
hDT = createDatatip(hDataCursorMgr,hHist); hDT.Cursor.DataIndex = maxInd;
grid on; hold on; grid minor; xlim([0,indMax+1]); ylim([0,10]);
%% // Update the plot and the datatip:
for indFrame = 2:size(data,1)       
   [~,maxInd] = max(histcounts(data(indFrame,:),edges));
   hHist.Data = data(indFrame,:);
   hDT.Cursor.DataIndex = maxInd;
   java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
   drawnow;
end
```

Which results in:

[image: The desired result 2]

---

Some notes \ observations:

- Datatips can only be added to supported data types, which currently only consist of `double` values (i.e. plotting something other than double doesn't let you add datatips to it, apparently). This is true for MATLAB 2015a. See another discussion about it [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/181581-problem-transitioning-guide-application-to-matlab-2014b-unexpected-error-when-using-data-cursor-zo).
- If datatips should contain some LaTeX-formatted strings, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011448/how-to-properly-display-tex-strings-in-axes-datatips-matlab-hg2) describes what needs to be done.
- The gif animations I used were created using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17463-movie-to-gif-converter).
- To center the animations in the posts, I used a combination of "alt+0160" and "alt+255".